# Creating an XML file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an XML file using java , the XML file is perfectly being created , for creating the elements of the XML file , I'm creating objects for different elements , my question is that what if I have an object named movie and inside the movie I have movieName , director etc, do I have to create different objects for each movie ? or is there a way where I can work with lesser amounts of objects ? I hope I've made myself clear with my question

to understand more in what I mean Here's the XML file :

```
<cinema>
 <movie id="10">
   <movieName>Army of Thieves</movieName>
   <director>Matthias Schweighöfer</director>
   <releaseDate>29/10/2021</releaseDate>
   <trailer>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ith2WetKXlg</trailer>
 </movie>
 <movie id=""></movie>
 <movie id=""></movie>
</cinema>
```

so in the XML file above , I basically want to add more than one movie with the same elements movieName,director,releaseDate,trailer, do I have to create different objects in Java for each element ?

Here's how I'm creating the XML file :

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class xmlBuilder {

public static final String xmlFilePath = "add your path here";

public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

        // root element
        Element root = document.createElement("cinema");
        document.appendChild(root);

        // movie elements
        Element movie1 = document.createElement("movie");
        Element movie2 = document.createElement("movie");
        Element movie3 = document.createElement("movie");

        root.appendChild(movie1);

        // set an attribute to movie element
        Attr attr = document.createAttribute("id");
        attr.setValue("10");
        movie1.setAttributeNode(attr);

        // movieName element
        Element movieName = document.createElement("movieName");
        movieName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Army of Thieves"));
        movie1.appendChild(movieName);

        // director element
        Element director = document.createElement("director");
        director.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Matthias Schweighöfer"));
        movie1.appendChild(director);

        // releaseDate element
        Element releaseDate = document.createElement("releaseDate");
        releaseDate.appendChild(document.createTextNode("29/10/2021"));
        movie1.appendChild(releaseDate);

        // trailer elements
        Element trailer = document.createElement("trailer");
        trailer.appendChild(document.createTextNode("https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
        v=Ith2WetKXlg"));
        movie1.appendChild(trailer);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFilePath));

        transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

        System.out.println("Done creating XML File");

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to create separate objects for each movie. All you need to do is surround the object with a loop and change the content in each iteration. You need to store the content in a list of movies and iterate over it with the loop. Here is an example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // movie elements
    Element movie = document.createElement("movie");
    root.appendChild(movie);
    // set an attribute to movie element
    org.w3c.dom.Attr attr = document.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("20");
    movie.setAttributeNode(attr);
    // movieName element
    Element movieName = document.createElement("movieName");
    movieName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Army of Thieves"));
    movie.appendChild(movieName);
    // director element
    Element director = document.createElement("director");
    director.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Matthias Schweighöfer"));
    movie.appendChild(director);
    // releaseDate element
    Element releaseDate = document.createElement("releaseDate");
    releaseDate.appendChild(document.createTextNode("29/10/2021"));
    movie.appendChild(releaseDate);
    // trailer elements
    Element trailer = document.createElement("trailer");
    trailer.appendChild(document.createTextNode("https://www.youtube.com/watch? v=Ith2WetKXlg"));
    movie.appendChild(trailer);
}
```